# Create a Footer in Word from a User Form

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I am very new to VBA. I am trying to create a script that will update footer in multiple word documents at the same time. The three things that need to be entered into the footer are: City and State, Store Number and Date. The footer will be centered but I can mess with the formatting later.

Currently I am trying to create a script that will:
Prompt the user to open up multiple Word Documents
Then show a user Form that prompts the user to enter the data in text boxes
Then take the information entered from those boxes and put it into the footer of the documents.

My first code that I created will do all of these things, but instead of using a UserForm, it uses 3 consecutive input prompts for the users to input the data and then create the footer out of that. Current code I have for this (No UserForm, only input boxes):

```
    Sub openAllfilesInALocation()
Dim Doc
Dim i As Integer
Dim varCity
Dim varStoreNumber
Dim varDate

Dim docToOpen As FileDialog
Set docToOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    docToOpen.Show
varCity = InputBox("City")
varStoreNumber = InputBox("Store Number")
varDate = InputBox("Document Date")

For i = 1 To docToOpen.SelectedItems.Count
'Open each document
Set Doc = Documents.Open(FileName:=docToOpen.SelectedItems(i))

With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
    .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = varCity & " " & varStoreNumber & " " & varDate
    
End With

Doc.Save
Doc.Close

Next i

End Sub
```

If I create a UserForm with 3 text boxes (one for City and State, one for Store Number, and one for Date), and a Submit button and Cancel button, what do I need to do to get it to reference the UserForm and take the data from the text boxes and input that into the footer?

I got the code (the one using InputBoxes) to work, but want to remove the InputBoxes and replace that with one userform. However, I don't know what to edit in the textbox and command button routines, or how to get my code to reference the Userform and the text boxes.

Comment: See http://www.gmayor.com/Userform.htm and http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/create_employ_userForm.html for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Let assume that the name of the userform is Userform1, the name of the textboxes TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3. The name of the Submit button is CommandButton1, and for the Cancel button CommandButton2.

If Cancel is clicked the Footnote will be deleted. If you don't want it then remove the 3 lines with the assignment in the CommandButton2_Click sub.

Date is checked for validation and apply the local format.

**Module**

```
Public varCity       'make avail for the userform
Public varStoreNumber
Public varDate

Sub openAllfilesInALocation()
Dim Doc
Dim i As Integer

Dim docToOpen As FileDialog
Set docToOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    docToOpen.Show

UserForm1.Show
'varCity = InputBox("City")
'varStoreNumber = InputBox("Store Number")
'varDate = InputBox("Document Date")

For i = 1 To docToOpen.SelectedItems.Count
'Open each document
Set Doc = Documents.Open(FileName:=docToOpen.SelectedItems(i))

With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
    .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = varCity & " " & varStoreNumber & " " & varDate
    
End With

Doc.Save
Doc.Close

Next i

End Sub
```

**Userform Code Module**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
varCity = UserForm1.TextBox1
varStoreNumber = UserForm1.TextBox2
varDate = UserForm1.TextBox3
On Error Resume Next
If IsError(CDate(varDate)) Then
UserForm1.TextBox3.SetFocus
Else
varDate = CDate(varDate)
VBA.Unload UserForm1
End If
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Me.hide
varCity = ""
varStoreNumber = ""
varDate = ""
End Sub
```

Recommend to add 3 Labels to identify the Textboxes.

Comment: This was perfect. Thank you so much for your response! I'm still learning VBA and this will definitely help me moving forward

Comment: Much simpler may be to create Building Blocks, store those in your template and just use the code to insert the Building Block. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#UsingVBABuildingBlock